# AlreadyExistsError while training a network on colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train an LSTMs network on Google Colab. However, this error occurs:

```py
    AlreadyExistsError: Resource __per_step_116/training_4/Adam/gradients/bidirectional_4/while/ReadVariableOp/Enter_grad/ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_Add/tmp_var/N10tensorflow19TemporaryVariableOp6TmpVarE
     [[{{node training_4/Adam/gradients/bidirectional_4/while/ReadVariableOp/Enter_grad/ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_Add/tmp_var}}]]
```

I don't know where can be the issue. This is the model of the network:

```py
sl_model = keras.models.Sequential()
sl_model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(max_index+1, hidden_size, mask_zero=True))

sl_model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_size, 
     activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences=True)))

sl_model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_size, activation='tanh', dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences=False))
            )

sl_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(max_length, activation='softsign')) 

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
sl_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc'])

batch_size = 128
epochs = 3
cbk = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard("logging/keras_model")

print("\nStarting training...")

sl_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
          shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_dev, y_dev), callbacks=[cbk])
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your runtime -- this happens when you have defined multiple graphs built in a single jupyter (Colaboratory) runtime.

Calling `tf.reset_default_graph()` may also help, but depending on whether you are using eager exection and how you've defined your sessions this may or may not work.